How to select the page for "relative to page" alignment?
In Inkscape, I can align objects relative to "the" page.

My document has 2 pages, created with the pages tool.

Is there a way to select the page that I want to align to? Is there something like an "active page"?

Objects are aligned to the page they are on. So,  just drag it or paste it onto the page you want it aligned to.

@BillyKerr: What does "are on" mean? Even if the majority (area wise) of the object "is on" one page, it may align to the other page. Even if the center of the object is on that page does not always help.

@BillyKerr: I found it. Obviously each object belongs to a certain page.

Well yes, but dragging an object onto a page does exactly the same as your answer. When I say "are on", I mean completely on the page, and within the page bounds of that page.

My object (background image) is larger than the page. Then that's the issue.

I see, but you didn't mention that. Kinda makes a difference.

An object belongs to a page. To change that, select the object and have a look at the status bar. You can find a page selector here:

The alignment will be made relative to that page.
The popup menu may look a bit weird sometimes, in which case you need to scroll with the arrows.

